# long delay evaluating programs when connecting via Windows Remote Desktop

Tags: remote-desktop

When I connect through to my PC using Windows Remote Desktop and try to elevate a program's admin privileges, for example when running a program installer, I get the UAC prompt.

However, after responding with either "yes" or "no" to the UAC prompt there is a "turquoise screen of wait" (which I suppose is at way better than a "Blue screen of Death") and a very long delay (30 seconds?) before the turquoise screen goes away and the system continues forward.

Is there any way to correct for this - so that there is no wait?

Thanks

PS: W10 on both machines

Comment: Try changing the UAC settings to down one level, so that it doesn't dim the desktop. May be a grahpical issue. Type `UserAccountControlSettings` in run and drag the slider down one level.

Comment: Thanks - but that doesn't sound so secure - would like to see if there is another alternative